# VBA script to add formula to a column if next column has data in that row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I've been working on a project and I have a **large** nested IF(countif(*),*,*) formula in excel to help me catagorize CSV files.

I'm trying to make it so when the CSV is imported (to cell B2) the A column will populate with the formula. I'm having troubles getting the formula to copy into even 1 cell, because no matter how hard I try it won't fit on one line. The formula is checking the contents of 3 different cells, with a possibility of 23+ outputs to give you an idea.

Is there anyway to:

1. Get a VBA script to copy the formula in (I've already recorded a
   macro and even the unmodified macro broke)
2. Make the macro ONLY fill as many rows with the info as possible **OR**
3. do the entire calculation in VBA and populate the cells accordingly.

Below is the formula I'm working with in each row, of which there can be a few thousand of in the CSV files.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(BZ2,"8075 *research*"),
IF(COUNTIF(BR2, "780 B*"),
    IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*ground*"),"51",
        IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*next*"),"52",
            IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*2*"),"53",
                IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*3*"),"54",
                    IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*charge*"),"546","Unclassified"
                    )
                )

            )
        )
    ),
    IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*ground*"),"25430",
        IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*next*"),"25431",
            IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*2*"),"25432",
                IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*3*"),"25433",
                    IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*charge*"),"2546","Unclassified"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
), 
IF(COUNTIF(BZ2, "780 B*"),
    IF(COUNTIF(BR2,"8075 *research*"),
        IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*ground*"),"251",
            IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*next*"),"252",
                IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*2*"),"253",
                    IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*3*"),"254",
                        IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*charge*"),"2546","Unclassified"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*ground*"),"15430",
            IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*next*"),"15431",
                IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*2*"),"15432",
                    IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*3*"),"15433",
                        IF(COUNTIF(AU2,"*charge*"),"1546","Unclassified"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )

    ),
    IF(COUNTIF(BR2, "780 B*"),"540",
        IF(COUNTIF(BR2,"8075 *research*"),"2540", "Unclassified"
        )
    )   
)
```

)

Comment: I'm confused, but for `3) do the entire calculation in VBA and populate the cells accordingly`, see Using UDF's at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: Are you using the `COUNTIF()` only to check if a certain keyword is present? Or am I reading your formula wrong?

Comment: Yes, COUNTIF() is only to check if the keword is present (not case sensitive) and set the True/Flase flags for the original IF statement.

@dcromley Thank you for the tutorials link, it's better than most I'd found! My biggest issue is still I'm uncertain how to make it ONLY run on X# of rows, where X is determined by the imported CSV. Obviously running it on thousand, or hundreds of thousands as the case maybe, extra rows isn't exactly desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I haven't tried this, but I think you should write a macro or UDF along these lines:

```
    Public Sub CheckMyCells()

    Dim thisCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
        For Each thisCell In .Range("RangeWithCSVValues")
            If .Range("BZ2").Value2 = "8075 *research*" Then
                If .Range("BR2").Value2 = "780 B*" Then
                    Select Case .Range("AU2").Value2
                        Case "*ground*"
                            thisCell.Value = 51
                        Case "*next*"
                            thisCell.Value = 51
                        Case "*2*"
                            thisCell.Value = 53
                         Case "*3*"
                            thisCell.Value = 54
                        Case "*charge*"
                            thisCell.Value = 546
                        Case Else
                            thisCell.Value = "ERROR!"
                Else
                    Case "*ground*"
                            thisCell.Value = 25430
                        Case "*next*"
                            thisCell.Value = 25431
                        Case "*2*"
                            thisCell.Value = 25432
                         Case "*3*"
                            thisCell.Value = 25433
                        Case "*charge*"
                            thisCell.Value = 2546
                        Case Else
                            thisCell.Value = "ERROR!"
                Else
                    '... Same thing again but with different values ...
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

And execute that after importing your data.
Obviously, `MySheet` is the name of the sheet in which you are working and `RangeWithCSVValues` is the name of the range containing the values you want to process, like `"A1:A2300"` for example.

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: this looks good, my only concern is how do I get it to do a variable range? 

So, basically sometimes the import could go from BZ2 to BZ937, other times it could go to BZ5476. I'd rather it not run on EVERY line, including ones not in use, since I doubt the file will ever be 1048576 lines big. (god save me if it is)

Comment: Never mind, I get it now - sorry. Thank you very much! I'll try something along these lines out and see if it works ^-^

Comment: Hey, glad to hear this helped you. You probably already figured this out, but you can use the `Selection` keyword to work with the selected cells. Or you can just open the macro and specify the range before running it (not very practical I know... but it's a start). Or you can just run it for an entire column and do a check in the cell value `thisCell.Value2 = ""` and stop the macro using `exit sub` when you reach an empty cell. Plenty of options :)

Comment: I did indeed manage to figure it out, using 
`Do While currentRow <= lastRow` 
and 
`With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UPS_CSV")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With`
The do while is filled with a massive amount of switch cases and function calls. All in all it's a lot longer than the Formula in each sheet was, but thanks to clean code is a lot easier to make sense of if anyone else needs to take it over after me!

Comment: Excellent! Just one request, if you think this was the answer to your question, could you please mark it as such? Thanks :)

Comment: Oops, thought I did sorry - I tried to up vote it and it wouldn't let me do to lack of rep, my apologies.